# Windows Phone 8 Lockscreen doesn't set when LockScreen.SetImageUri() is called

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, lockscreen

To start with, I have already added in the extensions to my app manifest, and my lockscreen image is changing, my problem stems from having it change multiple times.

In the app, I also have the ability for a person to hit a button where it will grab an image from the internet, save it to the storage then set it as a lockscreen. The first time someone hits the button, it will (most of the time) set correctly, although my problem is that when the button is hit again, it will often choose to not set, thus requiring the user to have to press the button multiple times in hopes that it sets correctly.

Here is my Button press code

```
    private async void Set_As_Lockscreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Set_As_Lockscreen_Click(): Entering");
        try
        {
            if (!contentLoaded) { return; }
            if (Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Awaiting Lockscreen_Helper.SetImage()");
                await Lockscreen_Helper.SetImage(new Uri(libraryObject.anime.cover_image, UriKind.Absolute));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { Debug.WriteLine("Set_As_Locksceen_Click(): Failed"); }
        Debug.WriteLine("Set_As_Lockscreen_Click(): Exiting");
    }
```

and Here is my Lockscreen Helper Class

```
public class Lockscreen_Helper
{
    private const string BackgroundRoot = ""; 
    private const string LOCKSCREEN_IMAGE = "lockscreen.jpg";
    private static int count;

    public static bool DeleteLockscreenImage()
    {
        Storage.DeleteFile(LOCKSCREEN_IMAGE);
        return true;
    }

    public static async Task SetImage(Uri uri)
    {
        //First Delete Old image
        DeleteLockscreenImage();

        Debug.WriteLine(uri.OriginalString);

        string fileName = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1];
        string imageName = BackgroundRoot + fileName;

        using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storageFolder.CreateFile(LOCKSCREEN_IMAGE))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Opening Client");
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                Debug.WriteLine("Grabbing File");
                byte[] hummingbirdResult = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
                Storage.isSavingComplete = false;

                Debug.WriteLine("Writing File");

                await stream.WriteAsync(hummingbirdResult, 0, hummingbirdResult.Length);
                Storage.isSavingComplete = true;

                Debug.WriteLine("File Written");
            }
        }

        await SetLockScreen();
    }

    public static async Task SetLockScreen()
    {
        bool hasAccessForLockScreen = LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication;

        if (!hasAccessForLockScreen)
        {
            var accessRequested = await LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync();
            hasAccessForLockScreen = (accessRequested == LockScreenRequestResult.Granted);

            Consts.HasAccessForLockscreen = hasAccessForLockScreen;
        }

        if (hasAccessForLockScreen)
        {
            // Maybe if I try setting it to another image then setting it
            // back to the downloaded image?

            //bool isAppResource = true;
            //string filePathOfTheImage = "Assets/defaultLockscreenBackground.png";
            //var schema = isAppResource ? "ms-appx:///" : "ms-appdata:///Local/";
            //var uri = new Uri(schema + filePathOfTheImage, UriKind.Absolute);
            //LockScreen.SetImageUri(uri);

            // thread.sleep(2.0); // Try having it wait 2 seconds before setting again?

            Uri imgUri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/" + LOCKSCREEN_IMAGE, UriKind.Absolute);
            LockScreen.SetImageUri(imgUri);
            Debug.WriteLine("Lockscreen Image Set");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Storage Code to delete the file

```
    public static bool DeleteFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (!DoesFileExist(fileName))
            return true;

        using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            storageFolder.DeleteFile(fileName);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**This code is just a slightly modified version of the code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571206%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [Channel-9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-33-Working-with-the-Lock-Screen-to-Display-an-Image)

Some things to note, the image is deleting, downloading and saving correctly, this i've checked through the Isolated Storage Explorer. I've even tried to set another image as the lockscreen, before settings my download image just incase filename similarities was messing it up. I even tried having it wait 2 seconds before trying to set again. None of the two work. Also Checking my output window, it is entering the methods.

I've been at this for a couple days now trying to figure this out and its just been racking my mind. Is there anyone who can help or at least offer up some advice?

Thank You.

Comment: Try debugging using breakpoints in visual studio. Put a breakpoint (F9) in Set_As_Lockscreen_Click method, and use Step Over(F10) to debug your program line-by-line to see why does it "choose not to set".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I implemented this feature on my application I had to resolve the following:

- Enable this option in the WmAppManiest.xml support for letting the application be a  background provider.
- Request permission for the application in order to be set as background provider.
- Set the image

  - To use an image that you shipped in your app, use ms-appx:///

    Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///background1.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); 
    LockScreen.SetImageUri(imageUri);
  - To use an image stored in the Local Folder, use ms-appdata:///local/shared/shellcontent
    ***Must be in or below the /shared/shellcontent subfolder***

    Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/shared/shellcontent/background2.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    LockScreen.SetImageUri(imageUri);

Based on (Module 7) http://rasor.wordpress.com/2012/11/30/wp8-jump-start-course/

Additionally in my case, I had to download the new background lock screen from internet periodically. One time it was not working because the OS was not reloading the image, even though the file was modified with the new downloaded image. The workaround was alternating the name of the downloaded file. Thus, the first time it uses:
"ms-appdata:///local/shared/shellcontent/background1.png"
the second time the app uses:
"ms-appdata:///local/shared/shellcontent/background2.png"
the next time it will use background1.png to repeat the loop.

Herb

Comment: It seems like my problem might be with the OS after all then. I have noticed that it does work every time if I set it to a different file name. So I'll switch it to alternate between two pictures like you have suggested.

Thanks!